# Is solution of a unimodular matrix equation integral?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a square full-ranked totally unimodular matrix, and $Ax = b$. Then does $x$ have to be integral?

This question follows from the wikipedia article on unimodular matrix:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. It seems to imply that $\det(A_i)$ in independent of the choice of $i$ (it doesn't appear anywhere on the right hand side), but is that true? I haven't studied totally unimodular matrices yet, so it might be

Comment: You're right. I rephrased the question to reflect what I'm actually asking.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ has integer entries and determinant $\pm 1$, then it follows that $A^{-1}$ also has integer entries, since $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}\mathrm{adj}(A)$, where $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ is the classical adjoint.

Therefore if $Ax=b$ and $b$ has integer entries, then $x=A^{-1}b$ also has integer entries.